# Limit user to 10 wrong pin code attempts Web Api #

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have been working on a simple web api that accepts a certain phone number and returns a pin code. The idea is that I want to delete/restrict the user to login if pin code is 10 times wrong. Could it be done in SQL Server or in c# code? 
All help is appreciated

Validate in business layer:

```
    public void validate(validateRequest vReq, headers head, ref validateResponse vRes)
    {
        vRes = new validateResponse();
        int isCorrect = vRes.isCorrect;

        Data dal = new Data();
        dal.OpenConnection();
        dal.valpinCode(vReq.pinCode, ref isCorrect);
        if (isCorrect == 1)
        {
            vRes.result.code = 0;
            vRes.result.message = "Successful";
            vRes.isCorrect = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            vRes.result.code = -3;
            vRes.result.message = "Access Denied.";
            vRes.isCorrect = -1;
        }
```

My valpincode in datalayer:

```
 public void valpinCode(string pinCode, ref int isCorrect)
    {
        try
        {
            using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(c.connstr))
            {
                if (db.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    db.Open();

                DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();

                param.Add("@pincode", pinCode);

                param.Add("@exist", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

                con.Execute("valpin", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                isCorrect = param.Get<Int32>("@exist");

                if (db.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    db.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           Common log = new Common();
            log.LogError(ex);
        }
    }
```

My valpin SP:

```
    @pincode nvarchar(50),
@exist bit output
AS
 BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM Users
    WHERE pinCode=@pincode)
BEGIN
    SET @exist=0
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
    SELECT *
    FROM Users
    WHERE pinCode=@pincode
    SET @exist=1
END
END
```

Users table:

```
idUser  phone   countrycode   pincode  
1      7006100      961        5716
12     7006107      961        77709
```

note that the pincode is generated randomly

Comment: It definitely can be done using C# and/or SQL.

Comment: pin code wrong count is data, so it should go to SQL server. the logic to initialize, increment, reset, and use that counter can be distributed to C#, SQL queries called from C#, or SQL stored procedures, depending on your choice of software architecture, data access method, and layering. You will only get useful answers here if you show the code you already have to go with your question.

Comment: sorry i updated the question with the codes i have

Comment: @dlatikay is there any example showing how it's done?

Comment: hardly. but with the code, now we're going somewhere. does the `Users` table already have an int column to keep track of the pin wrong count of each user? you will need another means of identifying the user (phone number?) and pass that to the stored procedure too, look the user up by phone number, see if the PIN matches and if not, update the counter, and if it reaches or exceeds 10, set another column to lock the user.

Comment: You definitely need to persist failed attempts in DB. So, what is exactly your question? you miss @user as parameter to use in where clause

Comment: I have edited the question again with the Users table

Comment: @Horaciux i need to limit the pin code entries to 10 wrong attempts. if so, send a "Access denied" message through postman

Comment: @dlatikay so should i add another column named "fail_count" that keeps track of failed entries? if so, how can i do it?

Comment: depends. I mean, how did you design the existing `Users` table? If you are in control of the database schema, use SQL Studio table designer. If you are using entity framework code-first, add it to the schema description and run the migration.

Comment: I am using SQL Server studio 2008, but the thing how can I keep track of the wrong entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute this script just once to add one column and set its value to zero for all users

```
alter table users
add invalidAttempts int null
;
update users
set invalidAttempts =0
select * from users
```

This procedure verifies if user does not exist (-1), if user is blocked(-2) if password is wrong (-3) and user and is is Ok (0)

Any invalid attempt is stored in the new field/column. If it's number reaches 10, the user is blocked. You need to establish another method for unblocking it. If the user is not blocked a valid login will reset invalid attempts.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE valpin @idUser INT, @pincode NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @pin VARCHAR(50)
  DECLARE @invalidAtempts INT

  SELECT @pin = pincode, @invalidAtempts = invalidAttempts
  FROM Users
  WHERE idUser = @idUser

  IF @invalidAtempts IS NULL
    RETURN - 1 --User does not exists
END

IF @invalidAtempts >= 10
  RETURN - 2 --blocked

IF @pin = @pincode
BEGIN
  UPDATE users
  SET invalidAttempts = 0
  WHERE idUser = @idUser

  RETURN 0 -- OK
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  UPDATE users
  SET invalidAttempts = invalidAttempts + 1
  WHERE idUser = @idUser

  RETURN - 3 -- wrong ping
END
```

You need to modify C# code to reflect this behavior. also, instead of using an output parameter use a return value `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;`

Comment: Thanks for the hard work but it didn't work in my SP? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've updated the question with the answer that worked for me